# PHP : undefined index error while updating database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

i am fetching data in text fields and then trying to update  it like this 
 then in the bottom this is what i'm doing

```
<?php                      
    $query= mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM page");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    if(isset($_GET['edit'])){?>
    <h1>About us </h1>
    <form >
        <div class="form-group"><textarea class="form-control" rows="10" name="con"><?php echo   $row['content'] ?></textarea></div>;
        <div class="form-group"> <strong>Projects Completed :</strong><input type="text" class="form-control" name="progress" value= "<?php echo $row['projects_completed']?>" ></div>
        <div class="form-group"> <strong>Projects In Progress :</strong><input type="text" class="form-control" name="done" value="<?php echo $row['projects_running']?>"> </div>        
        <a class="btn btn-primary"   href="about-us.php?update">Update</a>
    </form>
    <?php 
        }

    else{?>
        <a  class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="about-us.php?edit" name="edit">Edit</a>
        <h1>About us </h1>
        <?php 
            echo '<p>'.$row['content'].'</p>';
            echo  '<p><strong>Projects Completed :</strong>' .$row['projects_completed'].'</p>';
            echo  '<p> <strong>Projects Completed :</strong>' .$row['projects_running'].'</p>';
        ?>
    <?php };


?>

<?php if (isset($_GET['update'])) {
      $name= $_GET['content'];
      echo $name; 
?>
```

this is the error   i  get

> Notice: Undefined index: content in C:\wamp\www...

Please help me  to fix this ,

Comment: Where is the initialization of variable $row? I think you need echo $_GET['content']; and not echo $row['content'];

Comment: that's above in loop , i'm etching data properly issue comes when i press update

Comment: Your element's name is `con` not `content`. `name="con"`

Comment: It does not look like you are submitting a form, but just clicking on a link `<a class="btn btn-primary"   href="about-us.php?update">Update</a>`.

Comment: what should i do @Sean i m new please help me

Comment: 1st - fix the error that @chris85 points out in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848098/php-undefined-index-error-while-updating-database#comment55460850_33848098). 2nd - forms are submitted with either a `<input type="submit" />` or `<button>`, not a `<a>` (unless you are using javascript)

Comment: YES , now its working , Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

The notice messsage you see says that the array `$_GET` has not a `content` index. You can do something like that:

```
if (key_exists('content', $_GET)) {...} else {...}
```

instead of

```
if (isset($_GET['update'])) ...
```